# Font Awesome icons not rendering in IE on particular LAN

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts, font-awesome

We are interested in using Font Awesome icons for our project, and they seem great, but we noticed that the icons do not render in IE10 on our network.  It was first noticed on the official Font Awesome website, but I tried other sites that had them and they wouldn't render there, either.

The icons render in Firefox fine.  Weirder still, they render in IE fine on my PC at home.

I looked at the network traffic in the IE10 dev tools to see if maybe I was getting a 404 or maybe a font file was downloading but not being rendered.  However, it appears no font file is even being requested.  At least no requests for a font file of any type showed up.  The CSS loaded does reference FontAwesome and "Glyphicons Halflings".

This smells to me like some sort of local or LAN configuration issue, and I don't expect anyone here to directly troubleshoot that.  I'm hoping for some guidance regarding what to look for at this point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that group policy for IE forbade font downloads, and the section where that setting is provided was blocked off.  Enabling the setting allows fonts to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any AdBlock Plugin/Extension? This happened to me because I use uBlock in Chrome... and some Icons were not being displayed.

Comment: Nope, no ad blockers.  :(

Comment: I searched about this problem and found this [link](http://www.pie-solutions.com/font-awesome-ie9-ie10-problem/).
Have you tried this?

Comment: I'm noticing the problem on multiple external sites (including the Font Awesome site on github).  Thus, I don't have access to any server-side files to try changes.  I suppose it's possible that the few sites I checked all have this problem, and if that is indeed the problem, it would be easy enough for us to fix.  Do you know any examples of sites that use FA icons and have this implemented?

Comment: Is your javascript disabled?

Comment: Also, are you on a secure server?

Comment: JS enabled.  I am behind corporate firewall.